# Replace text between quotes in XML

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to find a way to change unknown text (could be anything) in an XML file for a printer migration.
The text that is in question is 
PrintProcessor="hpcpp111"

The Print Processor section could contain anything as this varies depending on printer model, type and driver. I would prefer to use powershell if possible as I am trying to understand scripting and how it all works, but I find it a little confusing. I may need to manually edit thousands of these files as we are migrating 5,500 printers.
I have found some code that gets it close for example

```
function Reset-InfoPathTemplateLink {
Param(
[string]$FilePath,
[string]$FileExtension,
[string]$OldPath,
[string]$NewPath
)
$files = Get-ChildItem $FilePath -Filter $FileExtension
foreach ($file in $files) {
(Get-Content $file.fullname) |
ForEach-Object {$_ -replace $OldPath,$NewPath} |
Set-Content $file.fullname
} #end foreach
} #end function
```

and if I dot-source it and then run this command

Reset-InfoPathTemplateLink -FilePath "c:\test2" -FileExtension "*.xml" -OldPath "PrintProcessor="*"" -NewPath "PrintProcessor='"WinPrint"'"

The WinPrint gets added to the beginning of the current print processor, which isnt ideal. If anyone has tips on how to get this to work, or if they can suggest a better method of doing this I would appreciate it

Comment: So, are you trying to change PrintProcessor="anything" to PrintProcessor="Winprint"?

Comment: Add sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you can use PowerShell to replace a pattern within a text file:

```
$path="c:\myPath.txt"
(Get-Content $path) -replace '(PrintProcessor=")(.*)(")','$1WinPrint$3' | Set-Content $path
```